# How can I write a regex in Ruby that will determine if a string meets this criteria?

Tags: ruby, regex

How can I write a regex in Ruby 1.9.2 that will determine if a string meets this criteria:

- Can only include letters, numbers and the `-` character
- Cannot be an empty string, i.e. cannot have a length of 0
- Must contain at least one letter

Comment: The second criterion is redundant (already covered by the third one).

Answer (score 4):

```
/\A[a-z0-9-]*[a-z][a-z0-9-]*\z/i
```

It goes like

- beginning of string
- some (or zero) letters, digits and/or dashes
- a letter
- some (or zero) letters, digits and/or dashes
- end of string

Answer (score 1):

I suppose these two will help you: `/\A[a-z0-9\-]{1,}\z/i` and `/[a-z]{1,}/i`. The first one checks on first two rules and the second one checks for the last condition.

Answer (score 1):

No regex:

```
str.count("a-zA-Z") > 0 && str.count("^a-zA-Z0-9-") == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_regular_expressions.htm) tutorial for how to use regular expressions in ruby. With regards to what you need, you can use the following:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9\-]+$
```

The `^` will instruct the regex engine to start matching from the very beginning of the string.

The `[..]` will instruct the regex engine to match any one of the characters they contain.

A-Z mean any upper case letter, a-z means any lower case letter and 0-9 means any number.

The `\-` will instruct the regex engine to match the `-`. The `\` is used infront of it because the `-` in regex is a special symbol, so it needs to be escaped

The `$` will instruct the regex engine to stop matching at the end of the line.

The `+` instructs the regex engine to match what is contained between the square brackets one or more time.

You can also use the `\i` flag to make your search case insensitive, so the regex might become something like this:

```
^[a-z0-9\-]+/i$
```

Comment: According to http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html, `^` is the beginning of a line rather than the beginning of the string.